# How to get the DLL a cmdlet is loaded from?

Tags: windows, powershell, dll

I'm trying to track down where exactly a cmdlet comes from in Powershell on Windows 8. How do I track this down? I know which Module and such it is, but this doesn't help me to track down the actual DLL it's code is implemented in. How do I track this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Get-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849711.aspx) cmdlet to return information about a specific cmdlet, then simply return its `.DLL` property.

For instance, for `Get-ChildItem`:

```
(Get-Command Get-ChildItem).DLL
```

The output would be something like:

> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll

Comment: This command not works with exchange commands like get-queue :(

Answer (score 1):

For example if you wanted to know the DLL for Get-ChildItem:

```
(get-command get-childitem).dll
```